# Can a virtualenv created on Windows be used from WSL bash?

Tags: python, bash, cmd, virtualenv, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) for a test project (obeythetestinggoat) and had a ton of issues trying to get virtualenv to work from the shell or CMD to ensure I was using the latest Python version installed (3.6).

```
mkvirtualenv --python="C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" superlists
```

I can get both bash and CMD running the virtualenv, but both report different versions of Python.
CMD:

```
python -V
Python 3.6.0
```

Bash:

```
python -V
Python 2.7.6

python3 -V
Python 3.4.3
```

Since the venv was created with the CMD shell, I would think it would control the version used, and the Scripts folder shows python36.dll, so assume it should be 3.6.

So it seems like the Bash WSL environment is controlling what version is used, regardless of any ENV paths I set.  I think I might ditch the Windows approach and go use my Ubuntu install, but really want to understand what is happening here, especially in regards to the virtualenv as it seems to negate the purpose of it all if the shell is only using what came with it and will not use the version supposedly in the virtual env.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This shouldn't be any surprise at all. WSL is an Ubuntu distribution that runs on a Windows kernel. As this implies, *it's a whole different operating system*, but for the kernel. You should expect application versions to differ.

Comment: ...frankly, if a virtualenv you created under one operating system worked on a different one at all, I'd be very surprised -- yes, it's the same kernel, so the kernel knows how to exec Windows applications, but that doesn't mean a virtualenv created on Windows with Windows paths &c. will know how to set things up for a Linux shell, where the VFS tree &c. differs.

Comment: Yes I do get that WSL is a separate OS running, and I think I was thrown by creating the venv in the bash shell first still allowed me to run code in the editor (PyCharm and CMD) and vice versa, so I was assuming it was picking up the python in that venv.  But my version tests and what you replied with prove it is just running in the native install for that "OS".  The core issue was trying to install Selenium and run with it.  Finally got that working with PyCharm.  Thanks for replying!

Comment: 2y latter @ VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
`sudo apt install virtualenv` works